# Autoload error in php

Tags: php

I am trying autoload function in php. The files are all in the same directory.
I have a file called aviation.php with the following code:

```
class Avaitor{

    public function __construct(){

        echo "Fly high<br>";
    }
}
```

Then in my autoloader file I am trying to do this:

```
function __autoload($fileName){

    if(file_exists($fileName . ".php"))
        require_once $fileName . ".php"; 

}

//require_once "aviatior.php";
$pilot = new Avaitor();
```

But I am getting this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Avaitor' not found in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_oop/autoload.php:22 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/php_oop/autoload.php on
>   line 22

Just to test that require_once does find my aviator.php I tried it out and then commented it out.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: **Warning** This feature has been *DEPRECATED* as of PHP 7.2.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. Since the time that `spl_autoload_register()` function has been introduced, you shouldn't use this function anymore.

Comment: `aviatior.php` but class is `Avaitor`. See the difference?

Comment: And if you're on *nix systems - beware of case-sensitivity in file names.

Comment: thanks, stupid spelling :P

Comment: yeah, I am converting to spl_autoload_register() if I manage to avoid spelling errors in the future :)